# meaning of 'es soll eine Abschlusserklärung geben' in a news script

Tags: modal-verb

I saw this sentence in a newspaper yesterday.

> Das ist keinesfalls selbstverständlich: Beim G20 Gipfel soll es trotz Russlands Mitgliedschaft eine gemeinsame Abschlusserklärung geben. Der Entwurf sieht den militärischen Konflikt als Ursache für immenses wirtschaftliches und humanitäres Leid in der Welt.

This is the translation by Google.

> This is by no means a matter of course: at the G20 summit, despite Russia's membership, there should be a joint final declaration.  The draft sees the military conflict as the cause of immense economic and humanitarian suffering in the world.

The interpretation `soll es eine Abschlusserklärung geben` was translated to `there should be a declaration`. What does it mean?

1. an obligation (should)
2. a confidence (about the fact that there will be a declaration)
3. just a rumor the reporter heard

I want to know the exact nuance because I have not studied the grammar fully yet.

Comment: Your title and question missed an `eine`. I presume that's just a lapse.

Comment: I interpret this as an expectation/aim communicated by the summit's presidency (since there is a draft).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: Questions concerning machine translations are often not very well received, since the language aspect is often a side issue only.

---

I consider the translation as wrong, *should* is not reflecting the meaning.

*Obligation* (your possible choice 1) is simply too strong, nothing enforces a final statement. This is more a pressure caused by expectation: A convention without final statement is considered a failure, therefore the participants will strive for achieving one. In my opinion, your choice 2 is the closest.

While *rumor* (hearsay) is a possible meaning in general, this is no sufficient justification for a report by a news agency. If they had independent sources for the same rumour ,the phrasing would need to reflect this. So in this context I don't assume your meaning 3 applies.

Comment: Thank you. I'm relieved my strongest guess was also at choice 2. :)